# Print as you type in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am having a little problem. How do you type a number and it gets printed out as you type. Eg

```
salary = input("Enter Employee Salary")
print("Salary: ", salary)
```

But this waits until you press enter and then it executes the print salary.
What I mean is as I type, the print salary shows the value as I type.

Comment: This alone would be enough: `salary = input("Enter Employee Salary")`, because you type and you see the value at the same time?

Comment: @Austin Input is normally echoed to the screen, yes. But that's different from that input appearing simultaneously on, say, the next line with the string `Salary: ` preceding it. For this, you need some library that monitors the keyboard directly, rather than simply reading from a stream like `input` does.

Comment: The feature you're trying to implement are *much* more complex than you think. You can either use `curses`, or capture key press, maintain a string and flushing the console every time.

Comment: or `print("Enter Employee Salary"); salary = input("Salary: ")` or `salary = input("Enter Employee Salary\nSalary: ")` might also be options to consider, if you care about linebreaks

Comment: I am actually using a raspberry pi connected to a 2x16 LCD screen and a numpad. I cant see the number am typing unless i hit enter

Comment: Use Adafruit library, and create a function triggered by your number typing.
`lcd = Adafruit_CharLCD(your config)`
then
`lcd.clear()`
`lcd.message(number)`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using the Keyboard Module**

If you want to print out your keyboard output while you type using the module keyboard, here's a full-featured example. You can't run this in IDLE because carriage returns don't work. There are probably easier solutions, but this is the best that I could come up with from the top of my head. I used the module [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).

```
# Imports
import keyboard

# Create variables
salary = ""
pre = "Salary:"

# Print the pre-salary text to start off
print(pre, end="\r")

# The callback function
def myfunc(event):
    # Grab the global variables
    global salary
    global pre
    # The keypresses that you dont want to log
    forbidden = ["shift", "Alt", "ctrl", "esc", "left", "right", "up", "down"]
    # Exits the program when the key ENTER is pressed
    if event.name == "enter":
        print("\n")
        raise SystemExit
    # Simulates a delete by taking away the last character in the salary and carrige returning a ' '
    elif event.name == "backspace":
        salary = salary[:-1]
        print(pre, salary, ' ', end="\r")
    # Creates a space (Without this it would just log 'space'
    elif event.name == "space":
        salary += ' '
        print(pre, salary, ' ', end="\r")
    # Checks if the keypress is in the forbidden list
    elif event.name in forbidden:
        return
    else:
        # Add the keypress to the salary
        salary += event.name
        # Print it out using a carrige return
        print(pre, salary, end="\r")

# When a key is pressed call the function myfunc
# Suppressing the output will allow me to print it myself
keyboard.on_press(myfunc, suppress=True)

# Puts it into an infinite loop
keyboard.wait()
```